# move text in media queries

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

i want to move one h1 element and one h2 element in media queries. on a big screen as i have it right know the elements are beside eachother but when you are on he phone i want the elements to stack on eachother. please help!! ps. i use bootstrap

```
<div class=" startpage-text mx-auto text-center d-flex just  justify-content-center ">
            <h1 class="name m-5 p-2 align-items-center col-sm text-center text-light ">Philip Lagergren Ydehed</h1>
            <h2 class="m-4 align-items-center col-sm text-center text-light info">Studerande inom webbutveckling fullstack på
                Nackademin</h2>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code. Its working for mobile deivce.

```
<div class=" row startpage-text mx-auto text-center d-flex just  justify-content-center col-xs-12 ">
   <h1 class="name m-5 p-2 align-items-center col-sm text-center text-light col-xs-12">Philip Lagergren Ydehed</h1>
   <h2 class="m-4 align-items-center col-sm text-center text-light info col-xs-12">Studerande inom webbutveckling fullstack på Nackademin</h2>
</div>
```